# python, assign a path of an excel file without know the full file name

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a dynamic path excel to my variable `source_path`.

However I dont know what the date of the file will be. it could be anything.. is there a way to just search my drive and look for just "weekly time report" and ignore the date? and read that file to source path?

```
from pathlib import Path    # to work with file paths
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import re
import os
import shutil


source_path = Path(r'...desktop...path\weekly time report 6.19.23.xslx')
dest_path = Path(r'networkdrive\weekly time report 6.19.23')

shutil.copyfile(source_path ,dest_path )
```

Comment: When you Googled "python how to find all file names containing string", what did you find?

Comment: i mean, i kind of want to delete the question but now someone has helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glob` to find the file, then move it with the same name

```
source_path = next(Path(r'...desktop...path').glob("weekly time report *.xslx"))
dest_path = Path(r'networkdrive', source_path.name)
```

The    `Path.glob` returns an iterator, use `next` to get the first one

Comment: glob is the best way to get a list of files if you do not know the file names or want the python code to get the list of files names rather than typing them all out.